# pyEnvironment 'time_step' doesn't match expected 'time_step_spec'

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to create an environment with tf_agents, but I have my _state type and my _observation_spec type which don't correspond.
Here's the code :

```
def __init__(self):

        self._action_spec = array_spec.BoundedArraySpec(shape=(), dtype=np.int32, minimum=-1,maximum=1, name='action')
        self._observation_spec = array_spec.BoundedArraySpec(shape=(2,), dtype=np.int32, minimum=-1, maximum = 500,name='observation')       
        self._state = np.zeros(2,dtype = np.int32)
        self._episode_ended = False
```

And I receive this error :

```
ValueError: Given `time_step`: TimeStep(
{'discount': array(1., dtype=float32),
 'observation': array([[0, 0]]),
 'reward': array(0., dtype=float32),
 'step_type': array(0)}) does not match expected `time_step_spec`: TimeStep(
{'discount': BoundedArraySpec(shape=(), dtype=dtype('float32'), name='discount', minimum=0.0, maximum=1.0),
 'observation': BoundedArraySpec(shape=(2,), dtype=dtype('int32'), name='observation', minimum=-1, maximum=500),
 'reward': ArraySpec(shape=(), dtype=dtype('float32'), name='reward'),
 'step_type': ArraySpec(shape=(), dtype=dtype('int32'), name='step_type')})
```

The problem therefore comes from these 2 lines :

```
self._observation_spec = array_spec.BoundedArraySpec(shape=(2,), dtype=np.int32, minimum=-1, maximum = 500,name='observation')       
self._state = np.zeros(2,dtype = np.int32)
```

And I noticed that `np.zeros(2).shape = (2,)`

I already saw this error on StackOverflow, but the solution was to precise the type in the array, what doesn't work here.

For information, the code run with these two lines :

```
self._observation_spec = array_spec.BoundedArraySpec(shape=(1,), dtype=np.int32, minimum=-1, maximum = 500,name='observation')       
self._state =np.array(0)
```

I tried to reshape, the array, to use a shape of (4,1), to precise the type, but none of this works..

Can anyone help me? Thank's !!

Everithing is specified above